# Without extending JTree is there anyway to force the update of the model after changing an object in the tree?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtree

I have a JTree that stores "ShipmentItem"s and the .toString() on them shows the quantity, then the name of the ShipmentItem. At some point I change the quantity of multiple items at once but the toString() doesn't refresh until I've actually clicked on that particular tree node. I don't want to have to extend JTree to use 'Property Fired' I just want to be able to refresh it so that it shows the update.

I tried jtree.setModel(tree.getModel()) this didn't seem to work at all.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change something to your `TreeModel` (which you do by adjusting the `ShipmentItem` objects) you must make sure your `TreeModel` fires the correct event. This will cause the `JTree` to repaint the correct part. If you for example started from the `DefaultTreeModel`, your extension should call [`nodeChanged`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html#nodeChanged%28javax.swing.tree.TreeNode%29) when the object of the node has changed.

Note: you do not have to adjust the `toString` method for correct rendering. The concept you are looking for is a [`TreeCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeCellRenderer.html) (check the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) for more information)